# Image fixed dimensions in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, frontend

I'm trying to give some images (of different sizes) the same dimensions. All my images should be 90x258 (w*h), but somehow I can't get this working.

This is my code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border BorderThickness="4,0,0,0" BorderBrush="BlanchedAlmond">
        <Image x:Name="Image" Source="{Binding Image}" Width="90" Height="258" />
    </Border>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="164">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10,0"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" Text="{Binding Authors}" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I played around with the `Stretch` property of my image but no matter what I select, the image will not be 90x258.

When using the default `Uniform` stretch it maintains the aspect ratio (I don't want that), when I choose `None` the image is shown in its original dimensions and `UniformToFill` and `Fill` will make the image so large that only a small part of it is actually shown in the image container.

Here's an example:

[image]

I want it to show the full cover of the book, in 90x258:

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try settings the height to auto and the stretch to Fill

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border BorderThickness="4,0,0,0" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue">
        <Image x:Name="Image" Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="94" Stretch="Fill" />
    </Border>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="164">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10,0"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" Text="{Binding Authors}" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```